# Access token from gmail is only valid for the specific application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, gmail-api

I am connecting Gmail account in my web app,for that I created a Gmail application in https://console.developers.google.com, from that I got secret and client Id, And after that I am connecting the user and I am getting the access token,

Now my question is,If I use the access token, In my different Gmail app will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

An access token generated using one app cannot be used with another app. You have to get the user authenticated in the new app and generate new token to use with the new app.

Comment: @sureshprasanana70, I tried it its working fine, I am able to connect with the acces token which I have got from another app in gmail, So can you please tell me from where did you find this answer..?